# Different JLabel declaration when click and drop at JPanel

Tags: java, swing, variables, drag-and-drop, jlabel

I made a program that simulates logic gates and I'm having a problem with my Logic Gates as `JLabel` by adding to my Drawing Canvas. When I drop two input (for example switch) that connected to wire, clicking the switch will change the color of wire connected to it. By clicking only one of the switch, the two different connected wires are changing color.

I just want to know how to do that when you click and drop `JLabel` that will be my x1, the next I click and drop `JLabel` will be now x2. How do you do it?

Comment: Post a link to an image.

Comment: You made a program that simulates logic gates and you're having a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Create *small* `groups` made up of *individual* `elements` and make them **unique**.

**For ex:** Two `JLabels` as Two `switches`, `Swing Line` as `wire`. This will be your one logical unit grouped into one. You will have multiple groups such as this. All groups unique.

**2)** Once you identify elements and their respective groups, you identify new `dropping elements` into *canvas* by detecting where in the canvas elements are being dropped. If `new element` is being dropped on a `Group` then `add` that element into the group. Then identify `to` or `around` what element this new unit is being dropped.

**For ex:** If *new* `JLable` is being dropped near by any *valid* `Swing Line` then join that `JLable` with that `line`. So, you will have `Switch` being joined to `wire`.

**Why Group approach ?**

By grouping elements into small groups, you can set conditions based on groupings. Conditions such as, elements from `group x` should not join with elements from `group y`. This grouping approach will give you flexibility if you want to set up `logical joining conditions`.

**Technicalities:**

Element co-ordinates will help you detect `where` or `on what` new element is being dropped

**How to do Drap-Drop in java ?**

Java Swing has support for operations like Drap-Drop, Cut, Paste etc.

Refer this for complete guide >> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I've got an idea now.